# How to create a 1.5 spaced text view in iOS?

Tags: ios4, textbox

I have a large chunk of text in a text view, and I was interested in making the line spacing 1.5 or double. Is there an way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** my mistake, did not realize that UIFont's metrics are so constrained. Below is what I *actually* do:

I would render the text as html in a web view. You have the full control of CSS.